# Configure Australian GST Taxes on Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.14

Tags: commerce

I would **like step-by-step instructions as to how to configure Australian GST Tax on a Commerce Kickstart site,** if possible using configuration only.

The business rules are:

**Primary Objevctives**

- Australian GST tax is 10%.
- It has to be included in the quoted price. So an item that is quoted as $11 would contain $1 of GST.
- The amount of contained GST has to be displayed as a separate item in the bill.
- It is only applied to orders being sent to an Australian shipping address. This includes the shipping cost itself, which is GST-free for orders going overseas.
- There can be GST-free items, which don't incur GST whether they are sent overseas or not.

**Secondary Objectives**

- Related to the third item above, technically one is not meant to show separate "(tax-free) Subtotal" and "Included GST" rows but for the time being I'm willing to ignore this legal requirement.
- Somewhat related, instead of just removing the GST for overseas orders I would prefer to still show the contained GST amount but have the line item as something like "GST (removed)" and then not have it included in the calculation. My gut feeling is that these two secondary objectives are related.
- There seems to be an issue that sometimes crops up if I'm testing within the one browser and it remembers my previous shipping address, so that when I change to an overseas shipping address between orders it doesn't update as I would have expected. Might be a bug in Commerce though, and I'm expecting this to be an edge case.

My basic strategy so far has been:

- Do a clean install of the latest Commerce Kickstart via Aquia Desktop
- Write out a strategy of how I'm going to implement the tax
- Implement using a combination of things based on Randy Fay's Conditional Tax video, commerce_australia module, various other patches/tax removal modules/etc that are buried in drupal.org
- tweak until I realise that I'm no closer. Pull out hair. Take a walk and try to come up with another strategy. Rinse and repeat.

Also, is anyone able to give me a clear answer to **what the difference is between how the tax is applied in Rules as opposed to if I access it from Taxes-->Configure Components?**

Apologies for the long post but I'm honestly at my wits end here. I can give more information on what I have tried so far but I'm worried I may pollute the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module maybe is useful.

> The Commerce Australia module provides a number of customisations for
>   Drupal Commerce (http://drupal.org/project/commerce) that allow it to
>   be better suited for deployment in Australia.
>
> Most notably, these include basic currency formatting for Australia
>   and workable GST (Goods and Services Tax) rules.

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_australia